# Implementing "Russian peasant multiplication using java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Here is the code I have written: I'm a beginner programmer and I'm not very efficient with code. Can anyone check if I can improve it?

Here is the link to the method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication

```
public static long RussianPeasantMult(long a, long b)
    {   
        int arraylen=1000;
        long[][] results= new long[2][arraylen];
         results[0][0]=a;
         results[1][0]=b;
         int index=1;

         while(results[0][index-1]!=1)
         {
             results[0][index]=results[0][index-1]/2;
             results[1][index]=results[1][index-1]*2;
             index++;
         }
         long sum=0;
         for (int i=0;i<arraylen;i++)
         {
             if(results[0][i]%2==1)
                 sum=sum+results[1][i];
         }
         return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Improve it in what way?  Is it incorrect in some way?

Comment: I tested it, it seems to work. So I was thinking maby we can improve the time complexity or any small trick that programmer has to make the code more portable, clean and so on.

Comment: In that case, this question is off-topic for this site.  It may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but please remember to check [their rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting.

Comment: You should calculate the sum as you go instead remembering the whole two columns of results.   And of course if you do remember the columns, you don't need to allocate or iterate through 1000 rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to put elements in arrays, etc. You can use bitwise operations, and update accumulators, like:

```
public static long RussianPeasantMult(long a, long b) {
    long sum = 0;
    while(a != 0) {
        if((a & 1) == 1) {
            sum += b;
        }
        a >>>= 1;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

We thus in each iteration we check if the last bit is set or not. In case it is set, we add `b` to the sum. Regardless of the last bit, we shift `a` one position to the right, and `b` one position to the left. We can stop from the moment `a` is zero (and thus all bits that are set are "shifted out").